# Could not initialize GsonConverter

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I have the following dependency (among others):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my servlet

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <!-- Application class name -->
            <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
            <param-value>notmyrealpackage.webservice.api.Leads</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But I'm still getting this message.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet RestletServlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.restlet.ext.gson.GsonConverter
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `GsonConverter`-containing jar in your deployable (EAR/WAR) and runtime classpath? That error is saying a class available at compile time is not available at runtime, which means it used it to compile but it's not available to your J2EE container when you try to run (probably not packaged correctly).